# Putting spaces into a PHP date format

Tags: php

In the PHP date function below, I would like to put a few spaces between "a" and "\N\e\w".  How is it done?

```
'l, F j, Y, g:i a \N\e\w \Y\o\r\k \t\i\m\e'
```

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Wouldn't it be a simpler solution to simply use <?php echo date(...) . '&nbsp;New&nbsp;York&nbsp;Time'; ?> ?

Comment: Maybe it is even better to output the non-wrapping part of the string into a `<span>` and set its `white-space` to `nowrap` (ideally in CSS). Let’s separate the concerns ;)

`<?= date('l, F j, Y, g:i');?><span style="white-space: nowrap;">a New York time</span>`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll need to insert:

> &\nb\sp;

for each space that you want. That will prevent any of the characters from being recognized as special date characters.

Comment: I needed also to escape the escape character to get this to work = `&\\nb\\sp;` FWIW

Answer (score 6):

Just a little comment: it works only in single quotes declaration, not in double ones. I mean
`date('j.&\nb\sp;n.', $date)` works as described, `date("j.&\nb\sp;n.", $date)` outputs mess.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, the `date()` function does not ignore any whitespace you put into the format string. So put as much space as you need in there.

You will probably, however, need to use `&nbsp;` for consecutive spaces in your HTML output, if you do not want browsers to ignore the extra whitespace.

Rather than put `&nbsp;` directly into your date format string (you would need to escape it of course), it would be better to do any necessary conversion of consecutive spaces to non-breaking spaces separately. Then you can have a single function that does that, and forget about putting `&nbsp;` in all your format strings. This will come in especially useful if you ever have to generate output that isn't HTML.

Comment: I tried both of those already.  The whitespace was ignored, and &nbsp returned some odd characters.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity's sake, you may just want to rewrite this like:

```
date('l, F j, Y, g:i a').' New York time';
```

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to not place the string literal inside the date formatting string, so you don't have to escape it:

```
$string = date('l, F j, Y, g:i a'). '       (or &nbsp;) New York Time';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert: `"l \&\\n\b\s\p\; F d Y"`

```
$date=date("l \&\\n\b\s\p\; F d Y","2018/08/17");
```

It is return with `Friday  August 17 2018`.

The difference is :
added double slash before `"n"`.

It works fine for me.
Please try

Comment: Only this one works for me on PHP 8.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put `\t` for each space between date and time value in `date` function of php ......
e.g............
          `date("d-m-Y \t h:i:s")`

Comment: But make sure to use double quotes i.e `" "` for format otherwise the `\t` will be translated to literal `t` instead of space